# Missing plugin.xml in org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.annotations 4.x.x

Tags: java, apache, maven

I'm evaluating the Apache Felix dependency management framework for my OSGi application. I've gotten it to run just fine using the programmatic approach. I was, however, not able to get the annotations to work. Maven (3.3.9) complains that it cannot find the plugin descriptor (`META-INF/maven/plugin.xml`) and refuses to build with the lastest version of the dm plugin (4.2.0). Here are the relevant excerpts from my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>                                                                     
    <plugins>                                                               
        <plugin>                                                            
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>                             
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>  
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>                                                           
        <plugin>                                                            
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.annotation</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>                                        
            <executions>                                                    
                <execution>                                                 
                    <goals>                                                 
                        <goal>scan</goal>                                   
                    </goals>                                                
                    <configuration>                                         
                        <log>info</log>                                     
                    </configuration>                                        
                </execution>                                                
            </executions>                                                   
        </plugin>                                                           
    </plugins>                                                              
</build>
```

Here's the relevant error message I get from Maven:

```
[ERROR] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.annotation:4.2.0 
    (/Users/grg2fr/dev/.m2/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.annotation/4.2.0/org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.annotation-4.2.0.jar):
    No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml -> [Help 1]
```

I checked the available versions of the `org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.annotation` bundle and noticed, that indeed, the `plugin.xml` was present up until version 3.2.0 and disappeared beginning with version `4.0.1`. I've tried to use Version 3.2.0 and while that was successful in that it built the bundle and generated the proper entries in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

```
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin                                          
DependencyManager-Component: META-INF/dependencymanager/<obfuscated>/EMSMicroservice                                                
Export-Package: <obfuscated>;uses:="org.apache.felix.dm,org.osgi.framework";version="1.0.0"                                         
Import-Package: io.vertx.core;version="[3.3,4)",io.vertx.rxjava.core.http;version="[3.3,4)",io.vertx.rxjava.ext.web;version="[3.3,4)",org.apache.felix.dm;version="[4.1,5)",org.osgi.framework;version="[1.5,2)"              
Import-Service: io.vertx.rxjava.ext.web.Router                                  
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"          
Tool: Bnd-3.0.0.201509101326
```

the component still wasn't activated during runtime. The documentation on the apache website is not helpful (dates back to 2011!). That in itself is probably a clear sign that I should not use the Felix dm service but I'd like to understand how the latest versions are supposed to be used.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Cheers
Georg

Comment: That JAR is a dependency, not a plugin, see http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-dependency-manager/tutorials/working-with-annotations.html

Comment: Thanks, @tome - this helped. I was thrown off by this page: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FELIX/Apache+Felix+Dependency+Manager+-+Using+Annotations+-+Quick+Start. Apparently that page is no longer valid for the current implementation of Apache Felix DM.

Comment: Indeed, they seem to have changed their mind. It is probably better now, as all plugin responsibilities are now inside a "plugin-only" maven module. The former `org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.annotation` probably had single responsibility principle issues.